# I have to do Empty String check for 6 attributes of my class which has total 7 attributes

Tags: java

I have to do Empty String check for 6 attributes of my class which has total 7 attributes, Is there any better way to do rather than checking each attribute separately ?

Comment: Of course you have to check each one, you can't just know it.  Alternatively, you can populate some variable whenever the attribute is set, but essentially you are still checking just at a different time.

Comment: Almost certainly: no.  Just do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one common method in class like this

```
class MyClass {
  String attr1, attr2, attr3;

  public boolean isValid() {
    return !attr1.isEmpty() && !attr2.isEmpty()  ;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am also thinking to do the same but not giving me happiness in adding 6 conditions.which also causes SONAR violation

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) api, you can set @NotNull attributes on 6 of the params. 
A note : Frameworks should not only be used if this is required at many places or is already being used as it comes with an overhead.

```
public class Abc{

   @NotNull
   private String var1;

   @NotNull
   @Size(min = 1, max = 4)
   private String var2;

   @Min(5)
   private int var3;

   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8, you can do like this:

create a generic class Validator :

```
public class Validator<T> {

private T t;
private List<Throwable> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();

private Validator(T t) {
    this.t = t;
}

public static <T> Validator<T> of(final T t) {
    return new Validator<T>(t);
}

public <U> Validator<T> validate(final Function<T, U> projection, final Predicate<U> filter, final String message) {

    if (!filter.test(projection.apply(t))) {
        this.exceptions.add(new IllegalStateException(message));
    }
    return this;
}

public List<Throwable> get() {
   return exceptions;
  }
}
```

in your validator class :

```
YourObject yourObject = new yourObject("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");

List<Throwable> result = Validator.of(yourObject)
    .validate(YourObject::getAttr1, a -> !a.isEmpty(), "attr1 should not be empty")
    .validate(YourObject::getAttr2, a -> !a.isEmpty(), "attr2 should not be empty")
    .validate(YourObject::getAttr3, a -> !a.isEmpty(), "attr3 should not be empty").get();
```

check if result is not empty.

If you are using java 7, you can adapt previous code like this :

```
public class StringValidator {

private List<Throwable> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();

private Validator() {

}

public static StringValidator instance() {
 return new Validator();
}

public  StringValidator validate(final String value, final String message) {

 if (value.isEmpty()) {
    this.exceptions.add(new IllegalStateException(message));
 }
 return this;
}

public List<Throwable> get() {
 return exceptions;
 }
}
```

in your validator class :

```
YourObject yourObject = new yourObject("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");

List<Throwable> result = Validator.instance()
    .validate(yourObject.getAttr1(), "attr1 should not be empty")
    .validate(yourObject.getAttr2(), "attr2 should not be empty")
    .validate(yourObject.getAttr3(), "attr3 should not be empty").get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am using java 7